# Conjecture about primes in a particular formula?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Consider the following formula:

$$ f(a,b) = \alpha - \beta = \underbrace{\left(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}{\prod_{i=1}^n  x_i}\right)^a}_{\alpha} - \underbrace{\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^b}_{\beta}$$

Where $ p_i$ is the $i$'th prime and $x_i$ is a variable which satisfies:
$ (x_i - 1)(x_i - p_i) = 0 $ . Also, $a$ and $b$ are integers. The number of $x_i$ variables is denoted by $n$.

### Conjecture $1$

There always exists choices for $ a$,$b$ and $x_i$ such that:

$$ p_{i+1} = \left(\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n p_i}{\prod_{i=1}^n  x_i}\right)^a - \left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^b$$

Why might this be true?

Consider $f(3,1)$ , $x_1=1$ and $ x_2 = p_2 =3 $:

$$ 2^3 - 3 = 5$$

As the number cannot be divisible by $2$ or $3$ as the number the resultant must be co-prime to $2$ and $3$ and given the number of possibilities we guess there must be a solution where $p_{n+1} = f $

### Conjecture $2$

Given a co-prime $a$ and $b$, the distribution of primes on average in  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is related by:

$$ \frac{\langle \text{Number of unique primes in } \alpha \rangle }{\langle \text{Number of unique primes in } \beta \rangle} \sim \frac{b}{a}$$

Where $\langle x \rangle $ is the average of $x$.
While instinctively I feel there that there must be a relationship between $a$ and $b$ and the number of primes in $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I have only done this for a limited number of cases I wasn't sure if it would be true.

### Questions

Can one either prove or disprove conjecture $1$ or $2$? If conjecture $2$ is false is there a better relation number of primes of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ compared to $ a$ and $b$?

Comment: ... You said $(x_i-1)(x_i-p_i) = 0$ ie. $x_i  \in \{1,p_i\}$. So you are looking at $(\prod_{i \le n} p_i^{1-c_i})^a - (\prod_{i \le n} p_i^{c_i})^b$ where $c_i \in \{0,1\}$. Also the $x_i$ depend on $n$, you need to say it. And $a,b$ are integers ?

Comment: Yes, $a$ and $b$ are integers ... The number of $x_i$ variables are $n$

Comment: You might find interesting the following article ( http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3/S0025-5718-1987-0866108-3.pdf), about recogning primes at a glance writing them as $p = P-Q$ where $\prod_{q\le \sqrt{p}} q \vert PQ$